# Can't get access to streaming replication stats in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, replication, monitoring

I have streaming replication which I need to monitor. So there is a special user for Zabbix. I don't want to use pg_mongz and decided to set my own queries to pg_catalog schema's view pg_stat_replication to get replication state.

When I use query:

```
select * 
from pg_stat_replication;
```

it returns replication state record for admin. But when I logged in as monitoring user it returns just:

```
pid, usesysid, usename, application_name
```

So such parameters as client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, backend_start, state, sent_location, write_location, etc. are empty.

First I granted rights to my user on schema and tables:

```
grant usage on schema pg_catalog to usrmonitor;
grant select on all tables in schema pg_catalog to usrmonitor;
```

but it didn't help. When I looked at view I found that query uses functions and granted execution:

```
grant execute on function pg_stat_get_wal_senders() to usrmonitor;
grant execute on function pg_stat_get_activity(integer) to usrmonitor;
```

But the select query still returns empty columns. What maybe the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, access to these fields is intentionally restricted to superusers.

As a workaround, you may use a function as a proxy with the SECURITY DEFINER attribute:

> SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with
>   the privileges of the user that created it.

So as a superuser (typically the `postgres` user), do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_stat_replication() RETURNS SETOF pg_stat_replication as
$$ select * from pg_stat_replication; $$
LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Then revoke/grant the permission to use that function so that only the monitoring
user is allowed to execute it:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION func_stat_replication() FROM public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION func_stat_replication() to usrmonitor;
```

Then `usrmonitor` should execute:

```
 SELECT * FROM func_stat_replication();
```

and it will have the same results as if it was superuser.

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks Daniel!   One suggestion:  If people only want to "expose" certain replication state values to public, then modify the function as follows (as an example):     `CREATE FUNCTION pg_stat_replication_by_user() RETURNS TABLE (client_addr inet, client_hostname text, state text, replay_lag interval, sync_state text ) AS
$$ SELECT client_addr, state, replay_lag, sync_state FROM pg_stat_replication; $$
LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER;
`

Answer (score 6):

Since PostgreSQL 10, it is as simple as :

```
GRANT pg_monitor TO monitoring_user;
```

(Source: https://pganalyze.com/blog/whats-new-in-postgres-10-monitoring-improvements)